# typeahead.js default select the first suggestion

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am using the angularJS library by sifyion for typeahead, which actually uses typeahead.js and bloodhound.js and jquery. I have typeahead.js v 0.10.2 and jquery 1.10.2.
My aim is to create a feature for search where user can only select from the suggestions. so i have implemented it in a way that if result from suggestion is not selected a query with Null parameter is submited else the suggestion is submitted. I have set my options as

```
minLength: 1,
hightlight: true,
editable: false
```

I have three datasets like:

```
var bloodhoundStores = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url:'/url/param',
        filter: function(stores){
            return $.map(stores,function(store){return {name: store.name}})
        }
    }
});
```

I call clear cache for all of them and initialize them after that, Just to let you know. I am not very expert in this, but doing so solves my purpose

```
bloodhoundStores.clearPrefetchCache(); (on all three datasets)
.
bloodhoundStores.initialize(); (on all three datasets)
```

then I set it up for suggestion rendering like:

```
{
    name: 'Locality',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: bloodhoundLocality.ttAdapter(), 
    templates:{
        header: '<h4 style="padding-bottom: 2px;"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>Locality</h4>',
        empty:['<p>','<span>No results found</span>','</p>'].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><span class="sentence-case">{{name}}</span></p>')
    }
}
```

My problem is if user types in a search word, i want the first suggestion, if there is one, to  be selected. I have looked up for solution in twitter typeahead.js github repository for solutions in issues. I haven't been able to figure out a way to have them work for me. Please help me out or suggest me a way to different way to implement it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also I have a problem with, normally right arrow auto-completes the search query, but if user presses down key, it features the next suggestion with the cursor at the end. Right arrow key now does not auto complete the query, user again has to press tab. Suggest me some workaround

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

I have a closure that encapsulates all of my search form logic, including the typeahead source (and related). It looks a little like this:

```
(function() {
  var $searchBox,
      doSearch,
      firstMatch,
      searchResultHandler,
      typeaheadCallback,
      typeaheadSource;

  typeaheadSource = function(query, cb) {
    typeaheadCallback = cb;
    doSearch(query);
  };

  doSearch = function(term) {
    // Do some stuff here to query.
    // When the results come back, fire off a call to searchResultHandler.
  };

  searchResultHandler = function(response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response.body); // I'm using sock.js in my app

    firstMatch = data[0].termToFillInSearchBox;

    if (typeaheadCallback) {
      typeaheadCallback(data);
    }
  };

  $searchBox.on("typeahead:closed", function(evt) {
    // Match what is in the search field against some expected pattern.
    // In my case, I'm looking for "Some Value.1234".
    // If the input doesn't match, and I have something in "firstMatch" then
    // substitute the value.
    if (! /\w+\.\d+/.test($searchBox.val()) && firstMatch !== undefined) {
      $searchBox.val(firstMatch);
      firstMatch = undefined;
    }
  });
}());
```